# How to redirect all external links to a separate disclaimer page and pass the hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

For a WordPress site, I want users to get redirected on clicking an external URL to a disclaimer page containing two buttons

1. Continue to the external URL
2. Go to homepage

I have written this script for adding a class "ëxternal" to all external hyperlinks.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(a => {
    a.classList.add(location.hostname === a.hostname || !a.hostname.length ? 'internal' : 'external');
});
```

In the disclaimer page, my button is like this `<a id="outgoingUrl" href="/new_url" class="btn btn--small outgoingHyperlink">Continue</a>`

I have created an event listener for external hyperlink clicks where the users will be redirected to /leaving-the-site/?q=THE_EXTERNAL_HYPERLINK

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery('.external').not('.outgoingHyperlink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    constructedUrl = "/leaving-the-site/?q=" + encodeURI(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
    window.location.href = constructedUrl;
 });

});
```

In my disclaimer page, I want to create the `href` of **continue** button dynamically by reading the query parameter from the URL like this

```
var completeUrl = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(completeUrl);
var passedVal = url.searchParams.get("q");
document.getElementById("outgoingUrl").href=passedVal;
```

Problem is that the **continue** button `href` is getting created like this `abc.com/page1/anotherpage?q=abc.com/page1/anotherpage` instead of this `abc.com/page1/anotherpage`

How can I fix this?

Comment: this is something going on, on your leaving-the-site page, can you show the code that makes the link on that page?

Comment: document.getElementById("outgoingUrl").href=passedVal;